# Explicitly relating two functions containing exponential terms

Tags: applied-mathematics

This is an extremely basic question for a forum like this, but I am unable to think of any workable approaches myself.

I have two functions related to the distribution of administered drugs in the body:

`c1(t) = a1*exp(-k11*t) - b1*exp(-k21*t)
c2(t) = a2*exp(-k12*t) - b2*exp(-k22*t)`

where c are concentrations, t is the variable time, and a1, a2, b1, b2, and k11..k22 are constants of O(1).

I would like to develop a relationship directly between c1 and c2 without the variable t, i.e. `C2 = f(C1)`

I had thought that there might be a way to exploit the fact that c1 and c2 are related by a simple transformation:

`c2(t) = alpha*c1(beta*t + gamma)`

but I don't know how to exploit this.

For my purposes, an approximate relationship would suffice. I initially thought of representing exp() through a Taylor series in one equation, solving for t, and substituting that into the other equation, but the approximation of exp() with a small number of terms is too poor.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

gyro

Comment: Your statement c2(t) = alpha*c1(beta*t + gamma) is certainly false in general.  Note that c2 involves four independent parameters, while alpha, beta, gamma is only three.

Comment: I think that my nomenclature may have been misleading. I believe that if one replaces t with `beta*t + gamma` as the argument to c1(t), the form of the resulting c2 resembles the original form (obviously, the constants would be different). Essentially, there is a shift and scaling with respect to time.

Comment: So, rephrasing, you have a parametrised curve in the plane and you want to write it as the graph of a function.  I think that you may want to ask this at math.stackexchange.com because this is not an appropriate question for this forum.

Comment: I apologize for asking a question outside of the scope of this forum. I should have read the forum rules more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose $k_{21} > k_{11} > 0$, $k_{22} > k_{12} > 0$, $a_1, a_2 > 0$.  Then for large $t$, $c_1(t) \approx a_1 \exp(-k_{11} t)$ and $c_2(t) \approx a_2 \exp(-k_{12} t)$, and so $$c_2(t) \approx a_2 a_1^{-k_{12}/k_{11}} c_1(t)^{k_{12}/k_{11}}$$
If we think of $b_1 e^{-k_{21} t}$ and $b_2 e^{-k_{22} t}$ as small perturbations,

$$ c_2(t) - a_2 a_1^{-k_{12}/k_{11}} c_1(t)^{k_{12}/k_{11}}
\approx -b_1 \exp(-k_{22} t) + \dfrac{a_2 k_{12} b_1}{a_1 k_{11}} \exp((k_{11} - k_{12} - k_{21})t) $$

and each term on the right can similarly be approximated by a constant times a power of $c_1(t)$.

EDIT: In general, perturbative methods rely on some parameter being considered "small".  If that is not the case, you can try other things, such as polynomial approximation on an interval.

Here is an example (implemented in Maple) of Chebyshev approximation.  I'll assume that $c_1(t)$ is monotonically decreasing 
for $0 \le t < \infty$ (otherwise you'll have trouble, because the same value of $c_1(t)$ can correspond to different values of $c_2(t)$).

```
  PolyApp:= proc(c1, c2, eps)
    local R0, R1;
    R0:= y -> c2(fsolve(c1(t)=y,t=0..infinity));
    R1:= chebyshev(R0,0 .. c1(0), eps);
    unapply(eval(R1(y),T=orthopoly[T]),y);
  end proc;
```

Here $c1$ and $c2$ are functions and $eps$ is the desired accuracy.  The result is a polynomial function $R$ such that $R(c1(t))$ approximates $c2(t)$ for $t > 0$ to within (approximately) $eps$.  For example:

```
c1:= t -> exp(-1.2*t)-1/2*exp(-2.1*t);
c2:= t -> 3*exp(-1.7*t) + exp(-3.1*t);
R:= PolyApp(c1,c2, .001);
```

$$ \eqalign{R := y \to &- 0.5739485035+ 3.733107019\, \left( 4\,y-1 \right) ^{13}+ 5.165874754
\, \left( 4\,y-1 \right) ^{14}\cr & - 15.04222352\, \left( 4\,y-1 \right) ^{
12}- 9.859797626\, \left( 4\,y-1 \right) ^{11}\cr &+ 17.62329104\, \left( 4
\,y-1 \right) ^{10}+ 10.37508690\, \left( 4\,y-1 \right) ^{9}\cr &-
 5.114479650\, \left( 4\,y-1 \right) ^{7}- 10.14476674\, \left( 4\,y-1
 \right) ^{8}\cr & + 0.7923349133\, \left( 4\,y-1 \right) ^{2}+ 0.2303317805
\, \left( 4\,y-1 \right) ^{3}\cr & - 0.1919266857\, \left( 4\,y-1 \right) ^{
4}+ 1.420849797\, \left( 4\,y-1 \right) ^{5}\cr &+ 3.156620283\, \left( 4\,
y-1 \right) ^{6}+ 4.856867429\,y\cr}
$$

And then, for example, to compare the results at $t=0.5$:

```
R(c1(0.5)), c2(0.5);
```

$$1.494803716, 1.494492770$$

Comment: Thank you for the helpful explanation and suggestions. I will try an approach along those lines.